# If a user leaves any information blank after being given prompts how can I exclude that data from the output (window.alert) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, null

I am prompting for 8 things and I want to have them appear in a alert box but only if the user enters something in the field otherwise I do not want it to include that info.

All of the info should be displayed in one alert box after confirming  that the user wants to review the info.

Also if the user does not want to see the info the script will end.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var name = prompt("Enter your fist and last name.");

var address = prompt("Enter your address.");

var city = prompt("Enter your city.");

var state = prompt("Enter your state abbreviation code.");

var zip_code = prompt("Enter your zip code.");

var dob = prompt("Enter your date of birth in MM/DD/YYYY format.");

var ssn = prompt("Enter your social security number as XXX-XX-XXXX.");

var answer = confirm("Do you want to review the information you entered?");

if (name === null || name == "") null;
if (address === null || address === "") null;
if (city === null || city === "") null;
if (state === null || state === "") null;
if (zip_code === null || zip_code === "") null;
if (dob === null || dob === "") null;
if (ssn === null || ssn === "") null;
else if (answer === true) {
    window.alert( "Your name is " + name + ".\n"
                + "Your address is " + address + ".\n"
                + "Your city is " + city + ".\n"
                + "Your state is " + state + ".\n"
                + "Your zip code is " + zip_code + ".\n"
                + "Your date of birth is " + dob + ".\n"
                + "Your social security number is " + ssn + "." );
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: This is a legitime question why people are @ss and marked the question down? I think sometime advance developer forget how everybody started in this business...

Answer (score 0):

```
var alertText = [];
if (name){
  alertText.push("Your name is " + name);
}

if (address){
  alertText.push("Your address is " + address);
}

if (city){
  alertText.push("Your city is " + city);
}

if (state){
  alertText.push("Your state is " + state);
}

if (zip_code){
  alertText.push("Your zip code is " + zip_code);
}

if (dob){
  alertText.push("Your date of birth is " + dob);
}

if(ssn){
  alertText.push("Your social security number is " + ssn);
}

if(anwser=true){
    window.alert(alertText.join('\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var yourname = prompt("Enter your fist and last name.");
var address  = prompt("Enter your address.");
var city     = prompt("Enter your city.");
var state    = prompt("Enter your state abbreviation code.");
var zip_code = prompt("Enter your zip code.");
var dob      = prompt("Enter your date of birth in MM/DD/YYYY format.");
var ssn      = prompt("Enter your social security number as XXX-XX-XXXX.");
var answer   = confirm("Do you want to review the information you entered?");

if (answer) {
    var message = [];

    if (yourname) message.push("Name: " + yourname);
    if (address)  message.push("Address: " + address);
    if (city)     message.push("City: " + city);
    if (state)    message.push("State: " + state);
    if (zip_code) message.push("Zip code: " + zip_code);
    if (dob)      message.push("DOB: " + dob);
    if (ssn)      message.push("Social security number: " + ssn);

    if (message.length) alert(message.join("\n"));
}
```

Clean and simple.